# Javascript google plus api? Email grabbing concern

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-plus

I noticed a website was displaying my email in the script tag of the DOM and it has sparked my curiosity. I believe it is google plus but I am curious to learn how sites access **the gmail email you have while logged in**

Do you know what this API is and how its working?

```
<script>
window.__SSR = {c: 25.0 ,si:1,e:'myName@DOMAIN.com',dn:'myFIRSTname 
lastNAME',a:'bubble',at:'AEIZW7RgsJq10Op\/wP0ZzQ+m5j2k5IHLQYFn30BdkVKqfe6uNFdTaBsxUcAFbcSjHw39naaaaaaa3aDaysPCWuNIg6kFflTylDqdUS+zz+GE\x3d',ld:[null,[1,25,[]
,1,90]
]
,r:'https:\/\/www.websiteIvisited.com\/',s:'widget',annd: 2.0 ,bp: {}, 
id:'https:\/\/www.websiteIvisited.com\/'}; 
document.addEventListener && document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
{gapi.inline.tick('wdc', new Date().getTime());}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is called "Google Sign-In for websites"

Its a very simple API and google abstracts most of the heavy lifting.Here is how they do it

1.The web developer just adds the platform.js which handles all the google login stuff

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

2. Then developer puts his CLIENT_ID (unique to a developer and website) and scope (part of user info. they want access for ) .There are many ways but most of the website use `<meta>` tags

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

3. Put login button.Again many options but for those lazy developers google gives a tag syntax which platform.js will parse and convert into a nice button with google logo.Note the `data-onsuccess="onSignIn"` part

```
 <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

4.Now when you visit the page platform.js will parse those meta tags to record client Id and scope.Then it creates login button and binds a click handler to show you a popup window for login .When clicked it would open a popup window with URL bar locked this is a secure window other websites cannot see its content.After you successful login platform.js requests data to google server on arrival of which it closes the popup and calls `onSignIn` with a parameter which contains all your data.Rest of it is just function calls

```
<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    alert('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    alert('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    alert('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    alert("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
  };
</script>
```

This info. gets sent your website (by ajax or form) which then inserted in a dynamically created script.